# Proxychains doesn't work as intended in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, proxy, kali-linux, socks-proxy

I am beginner to ethical hacking and trying to route my request using proxychains and tor referring to this YouTube video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d91w9D1FPIk). I did everything as shown in video and even after that it doesn't seems to work.

Till now my progress is as follows:

[image: Firstly I started tor service]

Then I edited code in `/etc/proxychains.conf` follows:

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 4
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.
#   

# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

# Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns 

# set the class A subnet number to usefor use of the internal remote DNS mapping
# we use the reserved 224.x.x.x range by default,
# if the proxified app does a DNS request, we will return an IP from that range.
# on further accesses to this ip we will send the saved DNS name to the proxy.
# in case some control-freak app checks the returned ip, and denies to 
# connect, you can use another subnet, e.g. 10.x.x.x or 127.x.x.x.
# of course you should make sure that the proxified app does not need
# *real* access to this subnet. 
# i.e. dont use the same subnet then in the localnet section
#remote_dns_subnet 127 
#remote_dns_subnet 10
remote_dns_subnet 224

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

# By default enable localnet for loopback address ranges
# RFC5735 Loopback address range
localnet 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
# RFC1918 Private Address Ranges
# localnet 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
# localnet 172.16.0.0/255.240.0.0
# localnet 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0


# Example for localnet exclusion
## Exclude connections to 192.168.1.0/24 with port 80
# localnet 192.168.1.0:80/255.255.255.0

## Exclude connections to 192.168.100.0/24
# localnet 192.168.100.0/255.255.255.0

## Exclude connections to ANYwhere with port 80
# localnet 0.0.0.0:80/0.0.0.0

# ProxyList format
#       type  host  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#       http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#       socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#           http    192.168.39.93   8080    
#       
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks5 127.0.0.1 9050
socks4 127.0.0.1 9050
```

And then tried to run `proxychains firefox www.duckduckgo.com` to get output as follow:

```
root@kali:~# proxychains firefox www.duckduckgo.com
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-request| www.duckduckgo.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: www.duckduckgo.com does not exist
|DNS-request| detectportal.firefox.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: detectportal.firefox.com does not exist
|DNS-request| detectportal.firefox.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: detectportal.firefox.com does not exist
|DNS-request| detectportal.firefox.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: detectportal.firefox.com does not exist
|DNS-request| detectportal.firefox.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: detectportal.firefox.com does not exist
|DNS-request| superuser.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: superuser.com does not exist
|DNS-request| detectportal.firefox.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: detectportal.firefox.com does not exist
|DNS-request| detectportal.firefox.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: detectportal.firefox.com does not exist
|DNS-request| cdn.sstatic.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: cdn.sstatic.net does not exist
|DNS-request| detectportal.firefox.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| www.duckduckgo.com 
|DNS-response|: detectportal.firefox.com does not exist
|DNS-request| detectportal.firefox.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: www.duckduckgo.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: detectportal.firefox.com does not exist
|DNS-request| detectportal.firefox.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: detectportal.firefox.com does not exist
|DNS-request| detectportal.firefox.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| duckduckgo.com 
|DNS-response|: detectportal.firefox.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: duckduckgo.com does not exist
|DNS-request| duckduckgo.com 
|DNS-request| detectportal.firefox.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: duckduckgo.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: detectportal.firefox.com does not exist
|DNS-request| detectportal.firefox.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: detectportal.firefox.com does not exist
|DNS-request| cdn.sstatic.net 
|DNS-request| ajax.googleapis.com 
|DNS-request| lh5.googleusercontent.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: cdn.sstatic.net does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: lh5.googleusercontent.com does not exist
|DNS-request| www.gravatar.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| i.stack.imgur.com 
|DNS-response|: ajax.googleapis.com does not exist
|DNS-request| www.googletagservices.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: i.stack.imgur.com does not exist
|DNS-response|: www.gravatar.com does not exist
|DNS-request| www.google-analytics.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| secure.quantserve.com 
|DNS-response|: www.googletagservices.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: www.google-analytics.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| sb.scorecardresearch.com 
|DNS-response|: secure.quantserve.com does not exist
|DNS-request| rules.quantcount.com 
|DNS-request| secure.quantserve.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: sb.scorecardresearch.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: secure.quantserve.com does not exist
|DNS-request| adservice.google.co.in 
|DNS-response|: rules.quantcount.com does not exist
|DNS-request| adservice.google.com 
|DNS-request| securepubads.g.doubleclick.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: adservice.google.co.in does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| superuser.com 
|DNS-response|: adservice.google.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| cdn.ampproject.org 
|DNS-request| pixel.quantserve.com 
|DNS-response|: securepubads.g.doubleclick.net does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: cdn.ampproject.org does not exist
|DNS-response|: superuser.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: pixel.quantserve.com does not exist
|DNS-request| ajax.googleapis.com 
|DNS-request| cdn.sstatic.net 
|DNS-request| lh5.googleusercontent.com 
|DNS-request| www.gravatar.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: ajax.googleapis.com does not exist
|DNS-response|: cdn.sstatic.net does not exist
|DNS-request| i.stack.imgur.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: www.gravatar.com does not exist
|DNS-response|: lh5.googleusercontent.com does not exist
|DNS-request| snippets.cdn.mozilla.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: i.stack.imgur.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: snippets.cdn.mozilla.net does not exist
|DNS-request| snippets.cdn.mozilla.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: snippets.cdn.mozilla.net does not exist
|DNS-request| www.googletagservices.com 
|DNS-request| www.google-analytics.com 
|DNS-request| sb.scorecardresearch.com 
|DNS-request| secure.quantserve.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| cdn.sstatic.net 
|DNS-response|: www.googletagservices.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| adservice.google.co.in 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: sb.scorecardresearch.com does not exist
|DNS-response|: secure.quantserve.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| securepubads.g.doubleclick.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: www.google-analytics.com does not exist
|DNS-request| sb.scorecardresearch.com 
|DNS-response|: adservice.google.co.in does not exist
|DNS-request| adservice.google.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: cdn.sstatic.net does not exist
|DNS-request| adservice.google.co.in 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: sb.scorecardresearch.com does not exist
|DNS-request| cdn.sstatic.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| qa.sockets.stackexchange.com 
|DNS-response|: adservice.google.com does not exist
|DNS-response|: securepubads.g.doubleclick.net does not exist
|DNS-request| superuser.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| rules.quantcount.com 
|DNS-response|: adservice.google.co.in does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: cdn.sstatic.net does not exist
|DNS-response|: qa.sockets.stackexchange.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: rules.quantcount.com does not exist
|DNS-response|: superuser.com does not exist
|DNS-request| qa.sockets.stackexchange.com 
|DNS-request| superuser.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: qa.sockets.stackexchange.com does not exist
|DNS-request| www.google-analytics.com 
|DNS-request| securepubads.g.doubleclick.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: superuser.com does not exist
|DNS-request| pixel.quantserve.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: securepubads.g.doubleclick.net does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: pixel.quantserve.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| pixel.quantserve.com 
|DNS-response|: www.google-analytics.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: pixel.quantserve.com does not exist
|DNS-request| tpc.googlesyndication.com 
|DNS-request| cdn.sstatic.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: tpc.googlesyndication.com does not exist
|DNS-request| securepubads.g.doubleclick.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| tpc.googlesyndication.com 
|DNS-response|: cdn.sstatic.net does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: tpc.googlesyndication.com does not exist
|DNS-response|: securepubads.g.doubleclick.net does not exist
|DNS-request| securepubads.g.doubleclick.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: securepubads.g.doubleclick.net does not exist
|DNS-request| securepubads.g.doubleclick.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: securepubads.g.doubleclick.net does not exist
|DNS-request| securepubads.g.doubleclick.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: securepubads.g.doubleclick.net does not exist
|DNS-request| securepubads.g.doubleclick.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: securepubads.g.doubleclick.net does not exist
|DNS-request| securepubads.g.doubleclick.net 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: securepubads.g.doubleclick.net does not exist
|DNS-request| www.google-analytics.com 
|DNS-request| qa.sockets.stackexchange.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: www.google-analytics.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: qa.sockets.stackexchange.com does not exist
|DNS-request| www.google-analytics.com 
|DNS-request| qa.sockets.stackexchange.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: www.google-analytics.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: qa.sockets.stackexchange.com does not exist
|DNS-request| www.google-analytics.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: www.google-analytics.com does not exist
|DNS-request| support.mozilla.org 
|DNS-request| www.google.com 
|DNS-request| stackoverflow.com 
|DNS-request| duckduckgo.com 
|DNS-request| superuser.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: www.google.com does not exist
|DNS-response|: stackoverflow.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| www.maketecheasier.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: duckduckgo.com does not exist
|DNS-request| stackoverflow.com 
|DNS-response|: support.mozilla.org does not exist
|DNS-request| duckduckgo.com 
|DNS-request| support.mozilla.org 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: www.maketecheasier.com does not exist
|DNS-response|: superuser.com does not exist
|DNS-request| www.adonespitogo.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: stackoverflow.com does not exist
|DNS-response|: duckduckgo.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: support.mozilla.org does not exist
|DNS-request| www.youtube.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| tools.kali.org 
|DNS-response|: www.adonespitogo.com does not exist
|DNS-request| www.kali.org 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: www.youtube.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: tools.kali.org does not exist
|DNS-request| askubuntu.com 
|DNS-request| github.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: www.kali.org does not exist
|DNS-request| tor.stackexchange.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: askubuntu.com does not exist
|DNS-request| www.howtogeek.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: tor.stackexchange.com does not exist
|DNS-response|: github.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: www.howtogeek.com does not exist
[Parent 11422, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (59): Connection reset by peer: file /build/firefox-esr-XulgD0/firefox-esr-60.2.0esr/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 353
```

For last 4 hours I tried everything I could try. Googled bunch of searches and visited many website but any of the solution given doesn't work for me.
If anyone has any Idea of why this might be happening then please suggest the solution.
Thank you in advance.

---

Please note the following :

1. I am using LIVE USB PERSISTENCE BOOT MODE
2. I am connected to Mobile phone via Wi-Fi to get connected to Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the 10 simple steps to be followed in order to work  with proxychains.
It doesn't matter if you installed tor or not, just follow my steps below.

**steps**

1. `apt-get install tor`

After installing "tor" you can use any editor tools (vim, nano or leaf-pad)
I use nano.

2. `nano /etc/proxychains.conf`
3. (I recommend) enabling dynamic_chain
4. make sure to check `no leaks to dns data` (enable)
5. at the bottom of the page you can add `socks5 proxy following ip` ( 127.0.0.1) follows by port shows as above ports.
6. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save it.
7. `service tor start`
8. `service tor status`
9. `service tor restart` (if you get any connection problem)
10. `proxychains firefox www.duckduckgo.com`

It should work fine with these steps, if you get any problem connecting to the IP just type `service tor restart`in the Terminal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked but I don't get what I was doing wrong. I think I followed the same steps but still it wasn't working and now it works like magic.In the question, You can see I did the same things previously. Can you please tell what I was doing wrong if possible?