# Proxychains and Firefox

Tags: kali-linux

I came across this topic:

[Proxychains doesn't work as intended in Kali Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1366476/proxychains-doesnt-work-as-intended-in-kali-linux?utm_source=pocket_mylist)

and I was wondering if we need to run this command " proxychains firefox www.duckduckgo"
or proxychains firefox [www.whatever.org](http://www.whatever.org), any time we want to visit a new website.

I mean, wouldn't it be sufficient just running " proxychains firefox" once to make
firefox work via proxchains for any website we are going to visit from then, until we close it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [ProxyChains](https://github.com/haad/proxychains) :

> ProxyChains is a UNIX program, that hooks network-related libc functions **in dynamically linked programs** via a preloaded DLL and redirects the connections through SOCKS4a/5 or HTTP proxies.

This means that ProxyChains does its job as the program is loaded into
memory, modifying the way that the libc library works for
*that program invocation*.

So, once `proxychains firefox` is run, Firefox will be programmed to use
the proxy for this invocation and any URL that you point it to.
However, once Firefox terminates, any effect is lost, and for the
next session you need to use the command again.

Comment: ok. so, it means that I don't need to run the command for any website I am going to visit. I can use Firefox until I close the session. Thanks